# Get the max date of dates in a column that are > than 6 days prior to another date column

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift

I have data where I want to compare what date was given 6 days or more prior to another date.

Example: the actual date time is 15th Jan 2022, I would like to see what the estimated time was 6 or more days prior to the actual using event update date. essentially data would be like

| event | estimate | actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22/01/22 | 14/01/22 | 15/01/22 |
| 13/01/22 | 14/01/22 | 15/01/22 |
| 01/01/22 | 06/01/22 | 15/01/22 |
| 27/12/21 | 01/01/22 | 15/01/22 |
| 15/12/21 | 28/12/21 | 15/01/22 |

I want to get the MAX event date that is greater than 6 days prior to actual date I should end up with below

| event | estimate | actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/22 | 06/01/22 | 15/01/22 |

I got as far as below just don't know how to get above?

```
select 
    foe.load_id,foe.estimated_arrival_time ETA, foe.event_date_time,
    fol.pod_vessel_arrival_time ATA, fol.load_number,
    datediff(days, foe.event_date_time, fol.pod_vessel_arrival_time) Days_event_ATA,
    datediff(days, foe.estimated_arrival_time, fol.pod_vessel_arrival_time) Days_ETA_ATA,
    event_source,
    shipper, carrier, provided_to_customer
from 
    public.fact_ocean_eta foe 
left join 
    hadoop.fact_ocean_loads fol on foe.load_id = fol.load_id 
inner join 
    (select 
         load_id, Max(event_date_time) event_date
     from public.fact_ocean_eta
     group by load_id) t2 on foe.load_id = t2.load_id 
                          and foe.event_date_time = t2.event_date
```

Answer (score 0):

worked it out by reading more

```
SELECT
    foe.load_id,
    foe.estimated_arrival_time eta,
    fol.pod_vessel_arrival_time ata,
    foe.event_date_time,
    foe.shipper,
    foe.carrier,
    fol.load_number,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY foe.load_id ORDER BY foe.event_date_time DESC) row_num
FROM
    fact_ocean_eta foe
LEFT JOIN fact_ocean_loads fol ON foe.load_id = fol.load_id  WHERE
foe.shipper = 'mondelez-ocean'
AND foe.event_date_time < dateadd (day, - 6, fol.pod_vessel_arrival_time) ORDER BY
foe.event_date_time DESC)                                      WHERE
row_num = 1;
```